# Add custom symbols to google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am doing a project based on google maps. Where i need to simulate the path that subjects have traveled. Any idea how to do that?

FYI My Application functionality is similar as this [Flightradar24.com](http://www.flightradar24.com/8.15,80.42/8)

Answer (score 1):

When creating a google.maps.Marker Object in Javascript you can specify a specific Image to be used in place of a pin with the Icon property. To simulate a path you can erase and redraw the pins. I would recommend saving all the pins to an array that you can then reference later to update and redraw the pins.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions

EX:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map,
            icon: pinType
        });
```